EXC_BAD_ACCESS (KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS)
JSC::MarkedBlock::aboutToMarkSlow(unsigned int)
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS)
I have solve crashanalytics bugs from firebase account that give one error how to solve this error in react natice ?
I have not get any solutions thats i have not implement any solution i have require to perfect solution for this error message.
